# Delete a file with vb.net which is open in another process

Tags: vb.net, filesystems

I create a `.txt` file in C++ in the application folder /Common/Send/Test.txt
Than I call a VB.net application from the c++ code
the Vb.net app read the test.txt content than send it to a Web-Server with POST request, than delete the file.

But its not delete the file, the VB.net app crashing when it need to delete the file.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(".\\Common\Send\Test.txt")
```

I am using this to delete the file, what can be the problem?
The problem is its write another program using this file, thats why it cannot delete, how can I stop my application 1st part? Because I read the file, but than its doesnt close it. I think thats the problem.

Comment: Well, if you have an error message and you keep it for yourself don't be suprised if any answer is just a guess.

Comment: I dont have error message, I just got Appname.exe stopped working.

Comment: @RichárdKiss: Look into the event log and paste the real error message here (either by editing your question or as an answer, if it actually answered your question).

Comment: And how do you know that this crash is caused by the delete operation and not from something else? If you are sure that the problem is there then add a Try Catch around your code and display the Exception.Message property

Comment: Its write another program using the file.

Comment: I edited my question!

Comment: @RichárdKiss you have close file than and than you can delete it.

Comment: Yep I got it, I just didnt think i need to close but now I know. sr.Close() and done. thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this to delete the file ...

```
    Try
        System.IO.File.Delete(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)  + "\Common\Send\Test.txt")
    Catch ex As Exception
        'it may not exist so no worries ...
    End Try
```

To address the issue of it being open in a different process, here are your options:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/661082/Delete-a-file-that-is-in-use-by-another-process-wi